# Misunderstanding something when passing by reference (C structures)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference

i'm doing some basic C coding and running into an issue that i can't figure out. So my current setup is that i have delcared a simple structure:

```
struct UserInfo
{
   WCHAR* UserName;
   WCHAR* ComputerName;
}
```

And from my main I want to create an instance of that structure, pass the structure by reference to two functions each of which will populate one of the two fields. my main code is:

```
void main()
{
   struct UserInfo userInfo;

   GetUserName(&userInfo);
   GetComputerName(&userInfo);

   return 0;
}
```

The two functions are as follows:

```
BOOL GetUserName(struct UserInfo* userInfo)
/*
Function calls the winapi function GetUserNameW to return the current
username in widechar format.
*/
{
    WCHAR UserName[USERNAME_MAXSIZE + 1];
    DWORD UserNameSize = USERNAME_MAXSIZE + 1;

    if (!GetUserNameW(UserName, &UserNameSize))
    {
        if (&UserNameSize != USERNAME_MAXSIZE + 1)
        {
            if (!GetUserNameW(UserName, &UserNameSize)) return FALSE;
        }
        else return FALSE;
    }
    userInfo->UserName = UserName;

    return TRUE;
}
```

and

```
BOOL GetComputerName(struct UserInfo* userInfo)
{
    LPWSTR ComputerBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD ComputerBufferSize = MAX_PATH;
    if (!GetComputerNameW(ComputerBuffer, &ComputerBufferSize))
    {
        if (&ComputerBufferSize != MAX_PATH)
        {
            if (!GetComputerNameW(ComputerBuffer, &ComputerBufferSize)) return FALSE;
        }
        else return FALSE;
    }

    userInfo->ComputerName = ComputerBuffer;

    return TRUE;
}
```

The issue i have is that it seems when the second function is called the data stored in the first value is overwritten. So for instance when going through the code the first function populates userInfo->UserName correctly with a pointer to my systems username.

When the second function is called user userInfo->UserName value seems to be overwritten, the second function runs fine and the userInfo->ComputerName is correctly populated. I'm confused to why this is happening? If i merge these functions into one like so:

```
BOOL GetData(struct UserInfo* userInfo)
{
    WCHAR UserName[USERNAME_MAXSIZE + 1];
    DWORD UserNameSize = USERNAME_MAXSIZE + 1;
    LPWSTR ComputerBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD ComputerBufferSize = MAX_PATH;

    if (!GetUserNameW(UserName, &UserNameSize))
    {
        if (&UserNameSize != USERNAME_MAXSIZE + 1)
        {
            if (!GetUserNameW(UserName, &UserNameSize)) return FALSE;
        }
        else return FALSE;
    }
    userInfo->UserName = UserName;

    if (!GetComputerNameW(ComputerBuffer, &ComputerBufferSize))
    {
        if (&ComputerBufferSize != MAX_PATH)
        {
            if (!GetComputerNameW(ComputerBuffer, &ComputerBufferSize)) return FALSE;
        }
        else return FALSE;
    }

    userInfo->ComputerName = ComputerBuffer;

    return TRUE;
}
```

This all works as expected, am i missunderstanding something about passing by reference? From my understanding &userInfo is basically passing passing a pointer to my structure and userInfo->somefield is actually modifying my structure not a copy structure as would be the case with passing by value. I don't understand why when passing the same struct to different functions each modifying a different field they are interfearing with eachother?

Thanks in advance for any help understanding this.

Comment: You are storing pointers to local variables (The string arrays). When you exit the functions (or the block they are defined it) they don't exist any more. and their memory may be reused for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays `UserName` and `ComputerBuffer` are non-static local arrays in the functions. This means their life ends when returning from the functions, so you cannot use pointers to them after returning from the functions.

You should allocate some buffer on the heap so that the data are not erased on returning.

Also you should use `WCHAR`, not `LPWSTR`, as the element for `ComputerBuffer` because the member `ComputerName` to assign that has type `WCHAR*`.

Instead of these:

```
    WCHAR UserName[USERNAME_MAXSIZE + 1];
    DWORD UserNameSize = USERNAME_MAXSIZE + 1;
```

```
    LPWSTR ComputerBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD ComputerBufferSize = MAX_PATH;
```

You should do these:

```
    DWORD UserNameSize = USERNAME_MAXSIZE + 1;
    WCHAR *UserName = malloc(sizeof(*UserName) * UserNameSize);
```

```
    DWORD ComputerBufferSize = MAX_PATH;
    WCHAR *ComputerBuffer = malloc(sizeof(*ComputerBuffer ) * ComputerBufferSize);
```

You should add

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to use `malloc()` if it doesn't already exists.

Comment: Don't forget to call `free` on the allocated memory when you are finished using it

Comment: Ah thank you that makes sense, beacuse my struct type is wchar* i am populating the field with pointers to the non-static local arrays which go out of scope after the function has ended.